# Find the shortest value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list like this one:

```
players = [
    {
      'name': 'jowick42',
      'stack': [[1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3]]
    },
    {
      'name': 'robot',
      'stack': [[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
    }
  ]
```

I want to automatically find the shortest value of 'name' between the two names. In this case robot should be what is found. Whether the shortest name is in the first dict or in the second one doesn't matter.

I don't know how to do this which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function

```
player = min(players, key=lambda player: len(player['name']))
print (player['name'])
```